# пишет не в сети

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

по идеи он должен писать статус человека, а пишет постоянно не в сети

```
@client.command()
async def user(ctx,member:discord.Member = None, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if member == None:
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Информация о пользователе", color=ctx.message.author.color)
        emb.add_field(name="Имя:", value=ctx.message.author.display_name,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=ctx.message.author.id,inline=False)
        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.online:
            d = " В сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.offline:
            d = " Не в сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить"
```

Comment: не понимаю, зачем вот это? if member == None: или вы просто не полный код вставили?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте слегка сократим ваш код и попытаемся сделать то, что вам нужно. Я как понимаю, у вас возникла проблема только со стаусами, поэтому сокращу код до них

Во первых вы зачем то проверяете - Если при написание !user не написали никакого пользователя, то код будет показывать только информацию о вас, но зачем же вам тогда member, если с ним никаких действий не происходит, поэтому исправил эту проблему.
Дальше вы зачем то хотите получать гильдию, но в коде она никак не фигурирует, опять же, скорее всего код не полный, но я на всякий случай убрал её.

Дальше у вас просто куча ужасных проверок) сократите код, избавьте мир от них) да и не понятно зачем вы каждый раз обращайтесь к дискорду что бы переназначить переменную

Ниже написал код, как вижу его я. В embed'ах вы потом просто от **member** их получайте

```
@client.command()
async def user(ctx,member:discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author


    statuss = {"online": "В сети",
        "offline": "Не в сети",
        "idle": "Не активен",
        "dnd": "Не беспокоить"}

    t = statuss[member.status.name]

    print(t)
```